# iOS6 iPhone 5 nothing clickable at bottom of screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, autoresizingmask

I have an app I am trying to convert and make ready for the new iPhone 5 screen size. I added the new Default-568h@2x image and I set my views to autosize in IB. The views look right, they stretch to fill the screen, but any button I put at the bottom is unclickable. It's like there is an invisible line towards the bottom, about where the old iPhone screen would stop, and anything below that line is unclickable. If I put the button right on this line, the top part is clickable but the bottom part is not.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem... http://anthonyprato.com/2012/09/20/iphone-5-problem-with-touches-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen/

Your UIWindow created in a nib needs "Full Screen at Launch" checked.

Comment: Yeah, 1 minute to search on the net and test your solution, but before that 3 hours trying understand my problem! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have `MainWindow.xib` in your project (and most newer projects don't), then you need one extra line in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` of your app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    [window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    ...
}
```

I put it in the beginning of the method.  Worked like a charm.