# iPhone 5 UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to update my App for the iPhone 5's larger screen real estate.  I have a tableview that has expanded to take up the full height of the screen by adding the Default-568h@2x.png to my project, but the bottom couple of cells are not responding to touched in the simulator or the actual iPhone 5.  Am I missing something?  It's like the bottom portion of the screen is not detecting touched (but just in my App not the others).

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: If I had to guess it would probably be something in your view sizing.  Are you using xibs or code to create it?

Comment: I'm using xibs not code.

Comment: Looks like someone else is having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533058/ios6-iphone-5-nothing-clickable-at-bottom-of-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes may be your window frame size in AppDel class or in XIB file of your project's appdel class is not as per iPhone 5 Screen.

And change window frame according 3.5 inch and 4 inch screen of iPhone

Answer (score 2):

This is whats working for me

In application didFinishLaunching method I added this -

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

In any other view controller, preferably in - (void)viewDidLoad;

```
UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
[self.view setFrame:[screen applicationFrame]];
```