# iphone5 compatibility tab bar coming 88 points above bottom line of screen

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-5, screen-size

I have added iPhone 5 compatibility by adding the default-568h@2x.png
However, the tab bar in my application does not come in the bottom as should be expected.

This tab bar is added via tabbarController in mainWindow.xib.

[image: screenshot]

NOTE: the bottom black part is clickable, but my view does not stretch itself to fit the screen.
I have tried the following already:
1) [window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
2) setting freeform/retina 4 inch display in xib
3) setting full screen at launch for window form xib
4) Removing mainwindow.xib and coding tabbarcontroller as the rootviewcontroller of window

EDIT:
Code in appDidFinishLaunching:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   // [self tabbar];
    self.tabBarController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   // self.tabBarController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

MainWindow.xib looks like: [image]

Comment: even [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851859/default-568h2x-png-is-not-enough-cant-tap-bottom-part-of-screen?rq=1) did not work

Comment: Are u using auto layout or auto resize mask

Comment: Auto resize mask
The application is from iOS 4.3, so cannot use auto layout

Comment: have you tried to set UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin to tabbarviewcontroller view

Comment: tried with IB and code : same result

Comment: try to set the window frame if the iPhone 5:-
 window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568); 
before set the rootview.

Comment: that's already done with [window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]: I have even logged the window size n it comes 568

Comment: Please share your code tabbar creation and setting views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad!..I was using some APIs to show/hide tab bar. Those APIs had hardcoded 480 specified for y.
oopsies!

Answer (score 0):

Your launch image has the wrong name: Instead of `default-568h@2x.png` it should be `Default-568h@2x.png` (note the uppercase D). The file name is case sensitive.