# UIViews and iPhone 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS6 iPhone 5 nothing clickable at bottom of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533058/ios6-iphone-5-nothing-clickable-at-bottom-of-screen)

I have an awkward issue with UIViews, I am upgrading an app to fit the iPhone 5 screen size, so I am extending the Views height to make the fit. At the bottom of the views there is a button, when I extend the view to fit iPhone 5 the button never responds to user interaction, its like there is another transparent views covering and blocking user interaction.

Anyone else seen this happen with UI resizing?

Comment: I haven't seen this issue, but I thought I would drop a note that people are more likely to want to help you out if you accept answers to some of your previous questions.

Comment: thanks Mike, I really didn't know how to do that. I am new here.